# Modify CSS properties with JavaScript without remplacing the older ones

Tags: javascript, css, properties, transform, mousemove

I'm trying to create a HTML element that moves according to the coordinates of my mouse. I'm using the 'mousemove' event and to move my element, I use the offsetX/Y event's property.

If I only apply a horizontal move for example (so I only use offsetX), it will works. But when I apply the vertical move, it won't works anymore. I use the 'transform' CSS property and I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. It's because I apply a new property to move vertically, but then I delete the old property that let move the element horizontally.

So do you know how can I add multiple CSS properties (the same) to an element ?
I have tried to just add them together with "+" or in the same ``, but it doesn't work.

I hope I have been clear, and sorry for my english :)

Thank you in advance for your help :)

My code :

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.box');
let x = document.querySelector('#x');
let y = document.querySelector('#y');
let area = document.querySelector('.area');

area.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  x.innerHTML = e.offsetX;
  y.innerHTML = e.offsetY;
  box.style.transform = `translateX(${e.offsetX}px)`;
  box.style.transform = `translateY(${e.offsetY}px)`;
});
```

```css
.area {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>X : <span id="x"></span></p>
  <p>Y : <span id="y"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()) with horizontal and vertical params instead of separate `translateX`/`translateY` calls.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `transform` property is a list of transforms. So set both `transformX` and `transformY` in the same assignment.

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.box');
let x = document.querySelector('#x');
let y = document.querySelector('#y');
let area = document.querySelector('.area');

area.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  x.innerHTML = e.offsetX;
  y.innerHTML = e.offsetY;
  box.style.transform = `translateX(${e.offsetX}px) translateY(${e.offsetY}px)`;
});
```

```css
.area {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>X : <span id="x"></span></p>
  <p>Y : <span id="y"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you overwrite the translateX style.

```
box.style.transform = `translate(${e.offsetX}px, ${e.offsetY}px)`;
```

solve your problem.

Comment: They know why it's not working, the question says **but then I delete the old property**

Comment: The code is correct. Your text just reiterates what they already wrote in the question, as if they didn't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: ..........................................................................................................................................